# Facebook Activity Page on Mobile web page

Tags: facebook, mobile

I'm creating a mobile app using web.

Is there any way to display Facebook Activity page, or share dialog on your Mobile app page? I mean Facebook Activity page displays and stays on the mobile app not outside, or in the browser but on the app I created.

Is there any way to do this?